# Why does the json file add the 31 at the end

Tags: javascript, arrays

So my problem is that currently im trying to select an object in a array. I get the selected object and sends it back updated. But currently it is putting the coins at the end of the json file too. My problem is that it's adding 31 to the end of the JSON file.

```
fs.readFile('/root/discordbot/games/coins.txt', "utf8", (err, data) => {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].id == message.member.id) {
                    data.push(data[i].coins += 31);
                    fs.writeFile('/root/discordbot/games/coins.txt', JSON.stringify(data));
                    message.reply("You got 31 coins.")
                    return;
                }
            }

    })
```

Don't get any error message but this is my json file with the fail placement of coins.

```
[{"id":"151780033025933312","coins":31},31]
```

The 31 at the end shouldn't be there. It needs to just update the correct coins to the id.

Comment: share /root/discordbot/games/coins.txt this file

Comment: The /root/discordbot/games/coins.txt is dispalyed it's the json text.

Comment: Because you push value 31 into array. `data[i].coins += 31` This will be some int value, not an object.

Comment: Yeah, but ins't it easier to handle a int instead of a string?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Who? Me? Your question was put on hold as off-topic, and I think the question is very well on-topic.. Please refresh the page.

Comment: I  see, don't know why that happened will try to edit the queston to clear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
if (data[i].id == message.member.id) {
    data[i].coins += 31;
    fs.writeFile('/root/discordbot/games/coins.txt', JSON.stringify(data));
    message.reply("You got 31 coins.")
    return;
}
```

You were also pushing an updated value to `data` array by this line `data.push(data[i].coins += 31);`

Comment: If my account was older i would give you an upvote. But thanks for clarrifying this for me. It fixed it

Comment: @FrederichPedersen no worries, Happy coding :-)

Comment: Because it needs to add 31 instead of setting the value to 31

Comment: @caramba There should some previous value in `coins`. he wants to add 31 into it, not setting 31.

Comment: @DevidasKadam can you help fixing this error im getting? ``` (node:24322) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
```